# Microstrategy / Oracle - slow performance

Tags: oracle, microstrategy

We have a Microstrategy / Oracle setup which has a fact table with 50+ billion rows (that is 50,000,000,000+ rows).

The system performance is very unstable; sometimes it runs OK but at other times it is very slow, i.e. simple reports will take 20 minutes to run!

The most weird part: if we add more constraints to a report (i.e. more where clauses) that end up in LESS data coming back, the report actually slows down further.

We are able to pick up the SQL from Microstrategy, and we find that the SQL itself runs quite slowly as well.  However, since the SQL is generated by Microstrategy, we do not have much control over the SQL.

Any thoughts as to where we should look?

Comment: It isn't clear if the same query always runs consistently, or if you get performance variation when nothing has obviously changed. OEM has advisors that might point to bottlenecks. Otherwise start with the execution plans for the generated SQL and see if they point to bad choices, missing indexes, etc. Without knowing anything about the data or queries it's basically impossible to guess what might help, unless your statistics are just out of date...

Comment: I'm tempted to say, you should look at job or freelance sites for a DBA. Barring that, you can start by generating plans for the queries that worry you most and trying to determine bottlenecks. If you're saying that the same report can run faster or slower at times, find out what else is happening in the system when it does run slower.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the SQL and see if you can add any more useful indexes. Check that the query is using the indexes you think it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Check that every column that is filtered has an index.
Remember to update the statistics for all the tables involved: with tables so big it is very important.
Look at the query plan and check that there aren't table scan on large tables (you can accept them on small look up tables)

Answer (score 0):

`EnableDescribeParam=1` in ODBC driver

Answer (score -1):

If your environment is like mine then what i will provide may help with your request if not it may help others.  we too have a table like that and after weeks of trying to add this index or that index the ultimate solution was setting parallel  on the table and at the index level.

report runtime 25 mins
alter table TABLE_NAME parallel(degree 4 instances 4); 
alter index INDEX_NAME parallel(degree 4 instances 4);

report runtime 6 secs.

there is criteria for a table to have parallel set up on it such as must be larger tha 1G,  but play with parallel threads to get most optimal time.